# Можно ли задать время жизни очереди в java?

Tags: java, java-8, очередь

Хочу, чтобы моя `BlockingQueue` жила определенное время (хранится она в синглтоне). То есть, если никто не пришел за данными в очереди в течении какого то времени, она удаляется. Можно ли это реализовать как то? Или, может есть уже готовые инструменты задания жизни для очереди?

Comment: Можно создать дочерний класс и переопредить методы доступа так, чтобы они фиксировали (напр. в специальном поле) время обращения. Потом время от времени (по таймеру или как еще) в классе, который управляет этой очередью, проверять разницу текущего времени и времени последнего обращения, и если эта разница превышает некий порог, очищать (или уничтожать) очередь.

Answer (score 1):

Это можно реализовать при помощи AOP или при помощи Dynamic Proxy. Вот демонстрация с использованием Dynamic Proxy:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    BlockingQueue queue = new LinkedBlockingDeque();

    InvocationHandler handler = new InvocationHandler() {

        private BlockingQueue queue = new LinkedBlockingDeque();
        private long callTime;

        private static final long TTL = 2000;

        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - callTime > TTL) {
                queue.clear();
            }
            callTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            return method.invoke(queue, args);
        }
    };
    BlockingQueue timedQueue = (BlockingQueue) Proxy.newProxyInstance(BlockingQueue.class.getClassLoader(),
            new Class<?>[]{BlockingQueue.class},
            handler);

    queue.add("aaa");
    queue.add("bbb");
    queue.add("ccc");

    timedQueue.add("aaa");
    timedQueue.add("bbb");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    timedQueue.add("ccc");

    System.out.println("Regular BlockingQueue implementation: " + queue.toString());
    System.out.println("Timed BlockingQueue implementation: " + timedQueue.toString());

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.println("Timed BlockingQueue implementation after one more timeout: " + timedQueue.toString());
}
```

Советую, всё же, посмотреть на AspectJ (одна из реализаций AOP).